# Unable to use FSelector package in R on mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: java, r, macos, rweka, fselector

I'm using OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.3 now.

When I tried to use `library(FSelector)` in R, errors pop out saying:

```
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RWekajars', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘FSelector’
```

Also, same thing happened when I tried `library(Rweka)` and `library(Rwekajars)`.

Why this happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Type this into the console

```
java -version
```

Then it will prompt you to install the Java SDK.